# Can't remove <script> elements before they render

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to piece together a chrome extension that will delete all script elements before they are rendered...  I think I am close, as it appears I am catching them ahead of time, but I just can't get them removed:

**content.js**

```
var mo = new MutationObserver(process);
mo.observe(document, {subtree:true, childList:true});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { mo.disconnect()
```

});

```
function process(mutations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mutations.length; i++) {
        var nodeArray = mutations[i].addedNodes;
        for (var j = 0; j < nodeArray.length; j++) {
            var n = nodeArray[j];
            if (n.nodeName == "SCRIPT") {
                deleteNode(n);
            }                
        }
    }
}

function deleteNode(node) {
    console.log("ATTEMPTING TO DELETE " + node.nodeName);
    node.remove();
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "This is just a test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://myRealUrl.com/internal/default.asp?*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It was asked a few times. In short all you need is to overwrite the page with a modified html of the original page: 1) fetch location.href, 2) use regexp replace to strip those scripts, 3) use document.open + document.write. [Example](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14164/code).

Comment: Very nice alternative!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

In most situations*, `<script>` elements are executed as soon as they are encountered by the parser, before the DOM tree has been fully constructed. (This is required to allow `document.write()` to work correctly, among other things.) There is no window of opportunity for an extension to interrupt this process.

([Here is the relevant portion of the HTML5 specification.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model))

If you want to prevent scripts from executing, one viable approach might be to set a Content Security Policy which does not allow scripting. Keep in mind that this will also disable inline event handlers (like `onclick`), though.

---

*: An exception is scripts which have the `async` attribute set. Most scripts don't, though.

Comment: Thank you...  I believe using a Content Security Policy is out though since I will need to allow JavaScript from other pages on this same site...  I believe Content Security cannot be limited to a single page.

Comment: Content Security policies are set by an HTTP header, so they can be controlled on a page-by-page basis.

Comment: Whenever I attempt it, I receive a "Specific paths are not allowed." error when loading the extension?

Comment: You can't add specific paths to your permissions, but you can examine the path of a request before setting the CSP header.